# Why does my XP system randomly go into suspend mode?

Tags: windows-xp, thinkpad

I searched and could not find this question ant where.

Occassionally, usually while using the mouse, my computer will suddenly go into suspend mode.

To my knowledge, there is no pattern to this other than stated.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Do you remember when the issue first appeared?

Comment: Some days ago...

Comment: Again today. I was on my chrome browser looking at the MuseScore site, I clicked on a link back to the main new forum posts and there was a beep and the browser minimized and the computer suspended. I just wait the few seconds that takes, press the power button briefly and it comes back up with everything intact.

Comment: It seems to be tied into my Chrome browser - today I pressed the "return to previous window" in the browser and it went into suspend mode.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment above says, it seemed to be tied to Chrome when I had many tabs loaded. Since I lessened the tabs and now make sure to shut Chrome down last, the problem seems to be soled. It has been at least a month or more since I had this happen.